# Setar valor de variável em InputText JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, aplicação-web, jee

Gente, estou com uma dúvida talvez até um pouco besta mas que não estou conseguindo resolver, estou iniciando no desenvolvimento web utilizando java e jsf, primefaces e estou com um problema na hora de alterar um registro.
Tenho uma pagina de listagem que contem o botão detalhar a partir dai abro um

```
<p:dialog header="Detalhamento de Turmas" widgetVar="turmaDialog" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
```

E la dentro listo meus dados:

```
 <p:outputPanel id="turmaDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value"> 

            <h:outputText value="Código da Turma" />
            <h:outputText value="#{controllerTurma.turmaAlterar.id}" />
            <h:outputText value="Nome / Descrição" />
            <h:outputText value="#{controllerTurma.turmaAlterar.descricao}" />
            <h:outputText value="Tipo Ensino" />
            <h:outputText value="#{controllerTurma.turmaAlterar.tipoEnsino}" />
            <h:outputText value="Turno das Aulas" />
            <h:outputText value="#{controllerTurma.turmaAlterar.turno}"/>                                              
            <center>
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Alterar"/>
            </center>

        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

meu problema é, ao tentar fazer o mesmo, porem passando os valores para um

```
   <h:inputText value="#{controllerTurma.turmaAlterar.descricao}"  />
```

o input fica em branco, como se o valor da variável fosse null, mas o mesmo valor está sendo listado la em cima. O que devo fazer para carregar meus dados em um inputText

Comment: Eu comentei, acabei excluindo, mas vou comentar denovo.
Você os `get`s até chegar em descrição, não? Sei que é boba a pergunta ainda mais que funcionou em um `outputText`, mas só para aliviar minha consciencia.

Comment: Gustavo, desculpa não entendi muito bem o que você quer saber :/

Comment: Mas sinceramente não sei o por que de não funcionar, isso é o que deveria ocorrer mesmo...

Comment: Você possui os métodos `get`, com qual a `Expression Language` conseguirá fazer reflexão e pegar o valor de descrição? Ou seja, dentro de `controllerTurma`, vc tem `getTurmaAlterar()` e dentro de `turmaAlterar` vc tem `getDescricao`?

Comment: Hm estranho, eu não tinha formatado a pergunta corretamente, desculpe.

Comment: Sim tenho, o problema ai é que para setar o valor que está no outputtext em um inputtext não estou conseguindo, o porque é que não estou entendendo

Comment: Isso não deveria ser um problema, sério. Assim que chegar em casa do trabalho tentarei recriar o problema. Até lá, por favor, deixa os códigos dos demais componentes, por favor, bean e turma.

Comment: Então gustavo, creio que os problemas não venham do bean e nem da entidade turma, porque eu consigo acessá-los normalmente, o meu problema está sendo somente para setar o valor deles em um Input, inclusive eu tenho um dataTable listando esses dados, porem, na hora de passar para um simples campo de texto ele fica nulo.

Comment: Fazendo alguns testes aqui acabei vendo um possível erro, na verdade os resultados estão sim sendo listados, apos botar no input o atributo disabled=true o valor é setado